# Jmeter workflow for Login with access token with multiple threads

Tags: jmeter

I have a django application to be tested using Jmeter. Here is the Workflow

- Admin user logs in , gets back access_token
- Creates a user, using access_token ,unique mobile and email
- Created User resets its password using OTP and a new password
- Created user logs into the application.
- I am using Reg Ex. extractor for accessing access_token and OTP

I am able to perform this with 5 threads, but as I increase the threads, it fails. Let me know what am I missing. Below is the screen shot Of My Jmeter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly fails. Whole JMeter test? Some specific sampler? Your application? How many users do you add, is it 6 or 600? You need to be more specific and include at least essential failure details.

In the meantime I would suggest the following troubleshooting options:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan. Given you use > 1 user you need to maintain a separate session for each login.
2. You need to use a separate admin account for each thread. If you have only one admin account - create users in loop using [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) as your test needs to be realistic.
3. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
4. Disable all the listeners during test run as they consume a lot of resources (especially [View Results Tree one](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)) therefore your test may simply fail due to lack of RAM, see [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing for detailed explanation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).